# Angular Material custom scrollbar not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

SOS!! I've tried many solutions to customize the mat-sidenav (the side drawer/navbar from angular material) but not working. It only works when from chrome dev-tools I remove an overriding "over-flow: auto" on an inexistent div, changes which I am not able to apply through css, the overflow property of the classes always turns to auto.
My Template

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" (backdropClick)="drawer.close()">
     <mat-sidenav #drawer id="drawer" mode="side" class="sidenav" fixedInViewport 
      (keydown.escape)="drawer.close()"> 
      <mat-toolbar>
       ....
       </mat-toolbar>
       <mat-nav-list>
         ...... //scrollable content
       </mat-nav-list>
     </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="none">
      ......
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

CSS

```
#drawer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
#drawer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgb(0, 12, 8);
}
#drawer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #262626;
}
#drawer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

[Screenshot from Chrome's dev tools of the additional div which is not in the template, if I remove the overflow:auto property of this div in dev tools, the custom scroll bar works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngdbA.png)

will appreciate alot any help. Need to remove the "overflow: auto" property of the screenshot div. Any other solution to customize the mat-sidenav is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to override a css property, add this in your css file:

```
.mat-drawer-inner-container {
 overflow: hidden !important;
 }
```

If that doesn't work then try adding `::ng-deep` in the beginning, just before class name.

PS: I have used overflow as hidden, you can change it as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solver the problem in global style.css by configuration the scrollbar at application level

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #D6E4F8;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #09347A;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #051B3A;
}
```